# How to style the li tag bullets (make them smaller) in with TailwindCSS,

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

[image: list of items with list bullets to large]

Really easy problem, but I still have been searching for a long time to find a solution, I need to style the list bullets to be smaller, and in Tailwind. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet . However you can use the font that you've used in the shared screenshot.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div>
    <h3 class="text-blue-400 font-bold">Key Discussion points</h3>
<ul class="list-outside list-disc ml-6 text-indigo-900 font-medium">
    <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sollicitudin convallis viverra.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sollicitudin convallis viverra.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sollicitudin convallis viverra.</li>
<ul>
</div>
```